# ASP.NET 4 WCF Data Service securing for desktop Java aplication

Tags: wcf, service, odata

I've read several entries on the web about securing WCF Data Services (OData). I would be glad to hear your recommendation about securing WCF DS assuming it will be consumed by Java client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a number of options available.  Since it's all REST requests, the client doesn't really matter too much (except that it rules out any Windows-specific integrated stuff).  :)

I've done some prototypes where I have an encrypted token in my request header which I grab in  the OnStartProcessingRequest event handler.  You have access to `HttpContext.Current`, so you can just grab the request header, validate it against your token store, and then either let the request continue or not.  The client, whether it's Java, C#, JavaScript or whatever would be responsible for creating the token and appending it to your request headers.

Last year, the WCF Data Services team put out a series of blog posts responding to some community criticism that WCF Data Services weren't not that secure.  They listed out a number of different scenarios on securing your WCF Data Services.  Two entries in particular that I think are appropriate for your situation are these:

[OData and Authentication – Part 4 – Server Side Hooks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/07/19/odata-and-authentication-part-4-server-side-hooks.aspx)

[OData and Authentication – Part 5 – Custom HttpModules](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/07/19/odata-and-authentication-part-5-custom-httpmodules.aspx)

You can find all blogs in the series [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/tags/authentication/).

I think those two links are useful because it's all about the server-side configuration.  OData support is also contained within [RESTlet extension](http://www.odata.org/developers/odata-sdk), but being a .NET guy, I can't give you much more info that that.  :)

I hope this helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your support. Can you advise me a bit more in my scenario? I'm going to intruduce login form in client application (java) so that only logged users can use with web service. How could I implement checking if entered user/password is valid? Should I pass the login/pass values over web service to DB to check if the pair is ok? Can you advise me a bit?